# configuring apache with mod_mono for .net app

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, mono

I'm having a huge problem getting mod_mono and apache configured to work correctly.  I've had this working at one time, but I can't seem to figure out where i'm going wrong.  I'm using mono-server4.

I'm trying to use a seperate port from the main website.  So I have in /etc/apache2/sites-available (with a link from sites-enabled) a vhost configuration that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:9999>
  ServerName XXX
  ServerAdmin web-admin@XXX
  DocumentRoot /var/xxx

  MonoServerPath XXX "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
  MonoDebug XXX true
  MonoSetEnv XXX MONO_IOMAP=all
  MonoApplications XXX "/:/var/xxx"
  <Location "/">
    Allow from all
    Order allow,deny
    MonoSetServerAlias XXX
    SetHandler mono
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
  </Location>
  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I used mono-server4-admin to create the application

```
mono-server4-admin --path=/var/xxx --app=/XXX --port=9999
```

When i start apache, it gives the error:

```
Syntax error on line 13 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/xxx:
Server alias 'XXX, not found.
```

This corresponds with the MonoSetServerAlias statement.  So I commented it out, and when I do that apache starts.  However, when I try to access the site, I get a 500 error.

The access log indicates that it's trying to access the app on port 80, rather than 9999.  I'm not sure what the problem is here.  **Can anyone help me get figure out where I went wrong?**

My mono-server4-hosts.conf contains this:

```
# start /etc/mono-server4/conf.d/RMRSite/10_XXX
     Alias /XXX "/var/xxx"
     AddMonoApplications default "/XXX:/var/xxx"
       <Directory /var/xxx>
         SetHandler mono
           <IfModule mod_dir.c>
              DirectoryIndex index.aspx
           </IfModule>
       </Directory>
# end /etc/mono-server4/conf.d/XXX/10_XXX
```

Also, my /etc/mono-server4/conf.d/XXX/10_XXX contains this:

```
This is the configuration file
for the XXX virtualhost
path = /var/xxx
alias = /XXX
vhost = localhost
port = 9999
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid question, do you have this in your Apache config?

```
NameVirtualHost *:9999
Listen 9999
```

Comment: Yes.  Sorry, tried to include all info I could but didn't want it to be too long.  If that were the problem it would be a different error though.